# When to use -al vs -ing

Tags: verbs, suffixes

If I have a verb that I want turned into a noun, should I use -al sufix or -ing?

Example: 
For verb "to archive", should it be "archiving" or "archival" ?
Hence, should I say "Document archiving is exciting" or "Document archival is exciting"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, [*archival* is an adjective](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archival) and not a noun.

In English, when a verb is turned into a noun, it generally takes the suffix ***-ing*** and it is called as a **gerund.** [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gerund) defines it. Note that you can use a gerund as the subject, the complement, or the object of a sentence.

That said,

> Document archiving is exciting

seems okay.

Another easy example is...

> Reading helps you improve your vocabulary.

*Reading* is a gerund there derived from the verb *read*.

Answer (score 0):

Using -al is not always going to turn the verb into a noun. Most of the times those words won't even exist in English. Meanwhile, if you use -ing form, it changes the verb to its noun form (gerund / verbal noun). So, it will be better to go with using "-ing".